# Data from the ORACLE Collection are not appearing on the output SELECT Statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to ORACLE PL/SQL COLLECTION and I am trying to understand why the data from the COLLECTION TYPE tCamRow are not appearing on the select statement function below when put in PL/SQL package. Please see the function below.

```
function SelectStmt return clob is
          
    vReturn clob;
    vFirstCondAdded boolean := false; /* Add to "where" vs create "and..." */
    
    
  tCamRow sample_data.assign_rules%rowtype; /* This type allows you to pass a row from the assign_rules table */

  begin
  
    vReturn := 'select ctbt.car_key' || chr(10) ||
               '                                    from sample_data.claims ctbt' || chr(10) ||
               '                                   where ';

    /* CarCd check */
    if((tCamRow.carrier_cd is not null) and (upper(tCamRow.car_cd) != 'ALL')) then

      vReturn := vReturn || 'ctbt.car_cd = ''' || tCamRow.car_cd || '''';
      vFirstCondAdded := true;

    end if;

    /* Acc check */
    if((tCamRow.acc is not null) and (upper(tCamRow.acc) != 'ALL')) then

      if(vFirstCondAdded) then
        vReturn := vReturn || chr(10) || '                                     and ctbt.acc = ''' || tCamRow.acc || '''';
      else
        vReturn := vReturn || 'ctbt.acc = ''' || tCamRow.acc || '''';
      end if;
      vFirstCondAdded := true;
    
    end if;


    dbms_output.put_line(vReturn);

    return(vReturn);
    
  
  
  exception
    when others then
      dbms_output.put_line('***SelectStmt***');
      raise;
      
end SelectStmt;/* function SelectStmt */
```

I am getting the select statment below:

```
select ctbt.car_key from sample_data.claims ctbt where
```

instead of

```
select ctbt.carkey  from sample_data.claims ctbt
                                   where ctbt.car_cd = 'sample' --data from tCamRow.car_cd
                                     and ctbt.acc = '123456' --data from tCamRow.acc
```

Comment: You don't seem to ever populate `tCamRow`? Where is the data in that record supposed to come from - presumably the `assign_rules` table, but what does that contain, and how do you decide which row(s) from that are used?

Comment: Thank you for asking. the data from tCamRow should be coming from the table sample_data.assign_rules. I wanted to pull all the rows from the assign_rules table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to populate your `tCamRow` record with data from your `assign_rules` table - it won't contain any data otherwise, hence it failing the `(tCamRow.carrier_cd is not null)` check and not entering that `if` block.

You can only populate the record with data from a single row, so you can do something like:

```
...
select * into tCamRow from assign_rules where some_id = some_unique_value;

if((tCamRow.carrier_cd is not null) and (upper(tCamRow.car_cd) != 'ALL')) then
...
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cAtuNuz2)

Note that this will only work if the query returns exactly one row. If there is no matching data then you will get a no-data-found exception (which you could handle and ignore by putting that query in a sub-block); if it finds more than one row then you will get a too-many-rows exception.

Your final query construction is only expecting a single row anyway, at the moment at least.

You could loop over multiple rows from a query, either with an explicit cursor and an explicit fetch into your record type (open + fetch), or with an explicit or implicit cursor that doesn't need a separate record variable. In either case though you would need to know how to combine the values from multiple rows into your final output - possibly a combination of `and`, or more likely `or` with parentheses (handled differently for the first row returned - so you don't start with `where or (...`). It's unclear if you need to worry about that at the moment though.

> I wanted to pull all the rows from the assign_rules table.

That only really makes sense if you `or` together all the pairs of conditions from each row - if your table has a row where `car_cd` is 'sample' and another row where `car_cd` is 'example' then those can't both be true at the same time in your final query.

So I think you're looking for something like:

```
function SelectStmt return clob is
    vReturn clob;
    -- second variable to handle the first cursor row differently
    vFirstRowAdded boolean := false;
    vFirstCondAdded boolean := false;
    
  tCamRow sample_data.assign_rules%rowtype; /* This type allows you to pass a row from the assign_rules table */

  cursor vCursor is
    select * from assign_rules;

  begin
  
    vReturn := 'select ctbt.car_key' || chr(10) ||
               'from sample_data.claims ctbt' || chr(10) ||
               'where';

    open vCursor;
    loop
      fetch vCursor into tCamRow;
      exit when vCursor%notfound;

      -- check there is something to add
      if (tCamRow.car_cd is null or upper(tCamRow.car_cd) = 'ALL')
          and (tCamRow.acc is null or upper(tCamRow.acc) = 'ALL') then
        continue;
      end if;

      -- don't add 'or' on first cursor result, but do on all subsequent ones
      if vFirstRowAdded then
        vReturn := vReturn || chr(10) || 'or';
      end if;
      vFirstRowAdded := true;

      -- using 'or', so enclose checks from each row (could finesse this...)
      vReturn := vReturn || ' (';

      -- reset this for every cursor row
      vFirstCondAdded := false;

      /* CarCd check */
      if((tCamRow.car_cd is not null) and (upper(tCamRow.car_cd) != 'ALL')) then
        vReturn := vReturn || 'ctbt.car_cd = ''' || tCamRow.car_cd || '''';
        vFirstCondAdded := true;
      end if;

      /* Acc check */
      if((tCamRow.acc is not null) and (upper(tCamRow.acc) != 'ALL')) then
        if(vFirstCondAdded) then
          vReturn := vReturn || ' and ';
        end if;
        vFirstCondAdded := true;

        vReturn := vReturn || 'ctbt.acc = ''' || tCamRow.acc || '''';
      end if;

      -- using 'or', so enclose checks from each row (could finesse this...)
      vReturn := vReturn || ')';

      dbms_output.put_line(vReturn);
    end loop;

    return(vReturn);
  
  exception
    when others then
      dbms_output.put_line('***SelectStmt***');
      raise;
      
end SelectStmt;/* function SelectStmt */
/
```

which with some sample data produces:

| SELECTSTMT |
| --- |
| select ctbt.car_key from sample_data.claims ctbt where (ctbt.car_cd = 'sample' and ctbt.acc = '123456') or (ctbt.car_cd = 'sample2' and ctbt.acc = '234567') or (ctbt.car_cd = 'sample3') or (ctbt.acc = '345678') |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4ddsyrN-)

Comment: Hi @Alex Poole,
My goal is to loop every row and get them into select statement like below:

select ctbt.car_key
from sample_data.claims ctbt
where ctbt.car_cd = 'sample' and ctbt.acc = '123456'


select ctbt.car_key
from sample_data.claims ctbt
where ctbt.car_cd = 'sample2' and ctbt.acc = '234567'

May I ask how to achieve that?